# SenderAuthentication: No authentication check passed. Email service

Tags: apex-email-service

I have create a email service to which I have a class attached to create contact record. When I send email from Gmail, redifmail I am able to receive email and contact is created but when I send a email from my personal company email id (myname@company.com) with company domain name I am not able to receive email. I have added the my company domain to my email service. When I send a email from my company domain  I am getting error message to my email id.

> An error occured while trying to deliver the attached email.
>   You may wish to report the following information to the owner of email_services@teaq.ap1.apex.salesforce.com.
>   SenderAuthentication: No authentication check passed.
>   The attached email could not be processed because:
>   No authentication check passed.
>   Final-Recipient: rfc822; email_services@iyr2.9-wr3teaq.ap1.apex.salesforce.com
>   Action: failed
>   Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 551 SenderAuthentication: No authentication check passed.
>   Status: 5.5.1
>   Please guide me how can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the email service and make sure that advanced email security is not checked.